# Parse JSON with VBA (Access 2010)

Tags: json, vba, ms-access, web

I need to update a currency table in MS-Access with a JSON file below:

```
{
"timestamp": 1465843806,
"base": "CAD",
"rates": {
"AED": 2.87198141,
"AFN": 54.21812828,
"ALL": 95.86530071,
"AMD": 374.48549935,
"ANG": 1.39861507
}
}
```

The VBA code is as follows:

```
Private Sub cmdJsonTest_Click()
Set MyRequest = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
MyRequest.Open "GET", "https://website.org/api/latest.json?base=CAD"
MyRequest.send
' MsgBox MyRequest.ResponseText
Dim Json As Object
Set Json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(MyRequest.ResponseText)
MsgBox Json("base")  
End Sub
```

The above code works correctly displaying a message box with CAD but I need to loop through and capture each currency code along with it's rate value. What syntax do I use to do this? I can provide the code for the function Json() function but did not see a way to upload it. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using this json parser https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON, use this code

```
Private Sub IterateDictionary(poDict As Dictionary)
    Dim key As Variant

    For Each key In poDict.Keys()
        If TypeName(poDict(key)) = "Dictionary" Then
            Debug.Print key
            IterateDictionary poDict(key)
        Else
            Debug.Print key, poDict(key)
        End If

    Next
End Sub
```

EDIT:
You have to modify the debug.print with whatever process you want to do. To use this from your code put this line after MsgBox.

```
IterateDictionary Json
```

Comment: Yes this is the json parser that I am using. Sorry if this is a stupid question but could you please outline how I would call your function from my function?

Comment: I see the results in the Immediate Window when I run the code and it is working. This is exactly what I needed to do - thank you!

Now I just have to figure out the best way to update the currency table. I'll have to create a temporary recordset and the either loop through each matching currency code and update or execute an update query.

Thanks again. How do I mark your solution as the answer?

Comment: @JohnC Glad to help, there should be a green check mark.

Answer (score 2):

You could also string parse. For example, if after key pairs for the rates:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetValues()
    Dim s As String, rates(), i As Long
    s = "{""timestamp"": 1465843806,""base"": ""CAD"",""rates"": {""AED"": 2.87198141,""AFN"": 54.21812828,""ALL"": 95.86530071,""AMD"": 374.48549935,""ANG"": 1.39861507}}"
    rates = Array("AED", "AFN", "ALL", "AMD", "ANG")

    For i = LBound(rates) To UBound(rates)
        Debug.Print rates(i) & ":" & GetRate(s, rates(i))
    Next i
End Sub
Public Function GetRate(ByVal s As String, ByVal delimiter As String) As String
    GetRate = Replace(Split(Split(s, delimiter & Chr$(34) & Chr$(58))(1), Chr$(44))(0), Chr$(125), vbNullString)
End Function
```

[image: output]